# Is this a worthwhile Prime Number Generator?

Tags: prime-numbers, algorithms, matlab

So I wrote a little bit of MatLAB to try to exponentially generate larger and larger primes. The main draw back is that because it is exponentially generating larger primes it will miss a lot of prime numbers in between the ones it finds. So I use the MATLab isprime() method to perform a primality test instead of rel.

Without the isprime() method the code will fail after generating 319 as the numbers 11 and 29 would not have been generated. With the isprime() method it gets to a prime on the order of 3e12 within seconds.

Has anyone seen an algorithm like this before? I had kind of thought I saw a pattern and went out to see if my algorithim would work. It did, just not as well as I would like.

Sorry if this isn't the right place to post this. I didn't really know where else to.

```
prime_list(1) = 2;  %this list size will grow with more primes
count = 0;          %this is counting distance of next prime to the nth found prime in the list
iterate = 1;        %this is for index through the prime_list
sub_count = 0;      %this is a for one of the prime generation fall back methods

while 1
    pass = 1;
    count_temp = count;

    %see if the next prime is 2*largest_prime-1, primary method of generating an exponentially larger prime

    for j = 1 : length(prime_list)
        if rem(count(j)+prime_list(iterate)-1,prime_list(j)) == 0
            pass = 0;
        else
            count_temp(j) = count(j) + prime_list(iterate)-1;
        end
    end

    %double check, fall back method because of gaps in primes
    if(isprime(2*prime_list(iterate)-1))
        pass = 1;
    else
        pass = 0;
    end

    %if it is a prime update the lists
    if pass
        iterate = iterate+1;
        prime_list(iterate) = 2*prime_list(iterate-1)-1;
        count = count_temp;
        count(iterate) = 0;
    else
        %if it wasn't, start from the largest found prime and look for the next prime one increment at a time (fall back method)
        pass2 = 0;
        while pass2 == 0
            while pass == 0
                pass = 1;
                count = count+1;
                sub_count = sub_count+1;
                for j = 1 : length(prime_list)
                    if rem(count(j),prime_list(j)) == 0
                        pass = 0;
                    end
                end
            end

            %double check if it really is a prime

            if(isprime(prime_list(iterate)+sub_count))
                pass2 = 1;
            else
                pass = 0;
            end
        end

        %once it is found to be prime, update the lists
        iterate = iterate+1;
        prime_list(iterate) = prime_list(iterate-1)+sub_count;
        count(iterate) = 0;
        sub_count = 0;
    end
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately, not really, no. It looks like you're just testing whether $2p - 1$ is prime for a known prime $p$, and it usually isn't. And your test for primality seems to primarily be based on whether it's divisible by something already on your list, which has really spotty coverage precisely because of the exponential growth.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for the insight! That was kind of my feeling. I just thought it was cool that it worked and got to what I thought was large prime numbers fairly quickly so I felt tempted to get feedback!

Comment: Why write your own when computer scientists have worked on this problem for decades and have very efficient algorithms??  In *Mathematica* `Prime[]` generates primes extremely efficiently, even up to extremely large values.

Comment: I drive like an hour to and from school each day so sometimes I start going down a rabbit hole. We were talking about potential wells and energy levels in class and then the difference between energy levels. And then n^2-(n-1)^2 I saw produced some primes. Then I got curious I wanted to see how often it worked. Then I saw cases where it didn’t work and devised a backup test. And I just went down a rabbit hole.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Why do anything that has been done before?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork $(1)$ The author used the "isprime"-command in MATLAB. $(2)$ I do not understand the argument that we should not try to implement an algorithm just because someone else has already done this. $(3)$ The author did not clarify how large the primes should be. Maybe, the goal is to break the current record, in which case the isprime-command would not help much.

Comment: @playingwithnumbers A method to generate larger and larger primes (in principle without limit) is unknown, otherwise it would not make sense to speak of the "largest known prime". The known algorithms can be used for quite large numbers, but huge numbers (lets say a million digits or more) are still very time-consuming, of course in principal, the algorithm works also for those numbers. If you want to prove the primality, you must either be content with somewhat smaller numbers or choose numbers of a special form.

Comment: @Peter:  There are a number of methods for generating primes without limit—some quite efficient.  One is implemented in *Mathematica*'s `NextPrime[]` function.  Then of course there is the classic (but inefficient) method of multiplying all known primes and adding $1$.  There is no guarantee you produce *every* prime by this algorithm, but that's a separate question.

Comment: @Arthur:  "Why do anything that has been done before?"?  Well one reason is that you're unfamiliar with what has in fact been done before... a very bad reason.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork "Without limit" is just not true. There is a practical limit, which is of course very large. And there is also a theoretical limit because we cannot store arbitary large numbers in a calculator. The point of this question is probably that we can construct ever larger primes (beyond the current record, lets say).

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Multiplying all (known) primes and add $1$ will probably not give a prime. We can also ensure a prime factor different from all primes we have chosen. Moreover, we would have to factor the huge number which is even more time-consuming. The "multiply and add"-method shows that there are infinite many primes, but that does not mean that a huge prime (and I mean huge, lets say , $10^9$ digits) can be found in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: @playingwithnumbers Please clarify which magnitude the prime numbers you want should have. Otherwise, a good answer cannot be given.

Comment: Do we really expect that a question poser with reputation = $11$ is hoping to compete with long optimized and parallelized code which found the largest prime, $2^{82,589,933} − 1$—a number with 24,862,048 digits—which took twelve days of non-stop computing on a machine with an Intel i5-4590T CPU?  Does the poser know what a Mersenne prime is?  What prior work has been done? 
 https://www.mersenne.org/primes/press/M82589933.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89027/discussion-between-peter-and-david-g-stork).